# Visual Studio SerialPort

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port, vb.net-2010

I got this code from windows c#

```
  private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.serialPort1_DataReceived);
        }
    }
```

and I am using this **[Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)** to convert it to windows form code.

I got this code after converting it

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
serialPort1.Open()
If serialPort1.IsOpen Then
    Me.serialPort1.DataReceived += New System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Me.serialPort1_DataReceived)
End If
End Sub
```

but I have a problem in `Me.serialPort1.DataReceived` see picture below

[image]

Comment: you need to use `AddHandler` in VB in place of `+=`.

Comment: @Plutonix where do I put it?.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks man